# MapBox interiorPolygons can not show the hole in some area

Tags: ios, mapbox, polygons

Platform:xcode 9.2 iOS objective-c
Mapbox SDK version: Mapbox-iOS-SDK (3.7.2)

Expected behavior
I want to dig some holes in some area in the world fog, most of area can appear. But some area cannot show a hole. For example the code below:
A hole of Hexagon in the
Ulitsa Malaya Polyanka, 5, Moskva, Russia, 119180
Latitude: 55.735024 | Longitude: 37.617188.

Actual behavior
No hole in the area
Ulitsa Malaya Polyanka, 5, Moskva, Russia, 119180
Latitude: 55.735024 | Longitude: 37.617188.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D lightCoordinate[6] = { {55.735024042991469,  37.617187500000007}, {55.742165827861974,37.595214843749993}, {55.75644547726997, 37.595214843749993}, {55.763583342064059, 37.617187500000007}, {55.75644547726997, 37.639160156249993}, {55.742165827861974, 37.639160156249993} };
NSUInteger numberOfLightCoordinates = sizeof(lightCoordinate) / sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D);
    MGLPolygon *lightPolygon = [MGLPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:lightCoordinate count:numberOfLightCoordinates];
NSArray<MGLPolygon *> *lightPolygonArray = @[lightPolygon];

CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCoords[6] = { {90, 0}, {90, 180}, {-90,180}, {-90,0}, {-90,-180}, {90,-180} };
        NSUInteger numberOfWorldCoords = sizeof(worldCoords) / sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D);
        MGLPolygon *worldOverlay = [MGLPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:worldCoords
                                                         count:numberOfWorldCoords
                                              interiorPolygons:lightPolygonArray];
        //the array can have more than one "cutout" if needed

        [self.mapBoxView addOverlay:self.worldOverlay];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with some trick. Divide the earth with north and south part. Each part with cutout arrays. The code show below

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D northWorldCoords[4] = { {0, -180}, {0, 180}, {90, 180}, {90, -180}};
        NSUInteger northNumberOfWorldCoords = sizeof(northWorldCoords) / sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D);
        _northWorldOverlay = [MGLPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:northWorldCoords
                                                         count:northNumberOfWorldCoords
                                              interiorPolygons:northLightPolygonArray];
        //the array can have more than one "cutout" if needed

        [self.chillViewController.mapBoxView addOverlay:_northWorldOverlay];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D southWorldCoords[4] = {{0, -180}, {0, 180}, {-90, 180}, {-90, -180}};
        NSUInteger southNumberOfWorldCoords = sizeof(southWorldCoords) / sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D);
        _southWorldOverlay = [MGLPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:southWorldCoords
                                                         count:southNumberOfWorldCoords
                                              interiorPolygons:southLightPolygonArray];
        //the array can have more than one "cutout" if needed

        [self.chillViewController.mapBoxView addOverlay:_southWorldOverlay];
```